# Modify LDAP user via a GUI in Python and Django

Tags: python, django, ldap

I am working on a web application for LDAP users to login and edit their attributes such as username, description etc. And I was wondering if there is a way to modify the attributes of the logged in user. The modify operator of the python-ldap3 library is the way to go, but I can only modify a specified user in the code itself.

Is it even possible to make this a general function for a logged in user or not? I searched for solutions, but I could not find anything.

This is my modify operator (modify.py):

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, MODIFY_REPLACE

s = Server('192.168.1.154', get_info=ALL)

c = Connection(s, 'cn=ldap_user,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com', 'Password', auto_bind=False)
c.bind()

c.modify('cn=ldap_user,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com',
        {'givenName': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['Test'])],
         'sn': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, ['User'])]})
print(c.result)

c.unbind()
```

By the way, I am using Django, so at this point, I do not even know where and what I have to do.

My edit_profile view:

```
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
args = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

my EditProfileForm:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False,
widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'first_name',

        }
    )
)

last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False,
widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'last_name',
        }
    )
)

email = forms.EmailField(max_length=30, required=True,
widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'type': 'email',
            'name': 'email',
        }
    )
)

password = forms.CharField(required=False,
widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'type': 'hidden',
            'name': 'password',
        }
    )
)

class Meta:
    model = LdapUser
    fields = (
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

A new `ModifiableConnection` class can be composed using `Connection` and a method declared to modify attributes. *e.g.*

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, MODIFY_REPLACE


class ModifiableConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.conn = Connection(*args, **kwargs)

    def _modify_attr(self, attrname, values):
         attr = {attrname: [(MODIFY_REPLACE, values)]}
         self.conn.modify(self.conn.user, attr)

    def unbind(self):
         self.conn.unbind()

    @property
    def firstname(self): pass

    @firstname.setter
    def firstname(self, val):
        self.modify_attr('givenName', [val])

    @property
    def lastname(self): pass

    @lastname.setter
    def lastname(self, val):
        self.modify_attr('sn', [val])



    def bind(self):
         self.conn.bind()

server = Server('192.168.1.154', get_info=ALL)

user = 'cn=ldap_user,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com'
mod_con = ModifiableConnection(server, user, 'Password', auto_bind=False)
mod_con.bind()

mod_con.firstname = 'Test'
mod_con.lastname = 'User'

mod_con.unbind()
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sule. But at the end, you still modify specific attributes (mod_con.modify_attr('givenName', ['Test'])
mod_con.modify_attr('sn', ['User'])
What I want is a function, that works for all users. So a user should type his e.g. name in the app and it will change it in the LDAP by clicking the submit button. Is that even possible or do I have to run your code every time for every user?

Comment: My example is tightly coupled to the currently connected user. Can a user modify attributes for some other user?

Comment: ohh no sorry. Only the logged in user can change his own data. I was just confused that you wrote 'Test' and 'User' in the code. Correct me if I am wrong, but should there not be any placeholder for 'Test' and 'User'?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. The main idea in the example is to expose a method for updating attributes of an entry. You will write a form that submits to a _view function_ or _class-based view_ that passes the user entry from the form. Say the user enters text as `"Firstname Lastname"`. You can split this in your view function and pass down appropriately. e.g.
`names = "Firstname Lastname"
firstname, lastname = names.split(' ')
mod_con.modify_attr('givenName', [firstname]`

It may be best to declare firstname and lastname properties in the `ModifiableConnection` class

Comment: ok that is super helpful. Thank you Mr. Sule. Do I have the call the class in the views? See above. I posted my forms and views. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Seen. Are you logging the user via LDAP or maintaining a separate login strategy in your Django application so that the LDAP integration only exists to modify LDAP user attributes?

Comment: I currently use the django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend from the django-auth-ldap library in settings.py. So this is the authentication. My login page is just requesting the username and password. Authentication has alsways been working with the backend, but I need the modify operator. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166541/discussion-between-geniusbehind-and-oluwafemi-sule).